# Bootstrap menu integration in WordPress with nav walker (:hover)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

There is basically no problem, but a feature I want to add. It's working as it's supposed to.
I am using Edward McIntyre's **wp_bootstrap_navwalker**

https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

The problem is if I make a page for example for the WooCommerce with this structure:

> > - ~> Shop
> > - ~~> My Account
> > - ~~~> Logout

The only working link will be 'Logout' (3rd level menu). All others will be removed.
Well that's fine but I've already made my menu to show up on :hover.

So the question is how to disable the click function (I am not sure how to explain it better). Here is the code that made the bootstrap on hover:

```
var slideDuration;
slideDuration = 100;
jQuery('.ddmenu li.dropdown').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(slideDuration);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut({ duration: slideDuration, queue: false }).slideUp(slideDuration);
});
```

I tried everything to disable the click event (event.preventDefault() .. etc), but it still opens the menu on hover and when you click on the link with sub-menu it adds an active class and does nothing. So the higher menu is yet unusable.

PS: This is the latest version of the nav walker so it removes the link but this is not really a problem it was breaking this even with the old one.

Answer (score 0):

When I built wp_bootstrap_navwalker for Bootstrap 3 it was built to conform the bootstraps confines where parent items have no URL associated and it only supports one level of dropdown. The walker for Bootstrap 2.3.2 ( https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/tree/For-Bootstrap-2.3.2 ) supports virtually infinite dropdowns, but also does not attach a link to parent items.

Typically in this situation I suggest rethinking the menu structure if you are building a responsive site and multi-level dropdown are almost always broken on mobile. That said I am intending to publish a more configurable version of the walker this weekend.

As for your question, im not clear on what your looking to achieve, if you can lay it out a little more clearly I will gladly help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* dropdown */
.dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
/*  shows the dropdown on hover*/
.navbar ul.nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;   
}
/* before and after */
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::before, .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::after {
    display: none;
}
```